# How can an instruction with a 32-bit register and a constant occupy just three bytes?

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly

I'm reviewing disassembly of some program in Visual Studio 2012 and see the following:

```
65F920F3  or          eax, 0FFFFFFFFh  
65F920F6  jmp         65F92157
```

Note the `or`. It occupies addresses F3-F5 which means it occupies just three bytes. The `eax` register is four bytes and so I assume the constant `0FFFFFFFFh` is also four bytes.

How does this instruction fit into three bytes?

Answer (score 8):

Because the constant 0xFFFFFFFF aka -1 fits in a signed byte, so it can use the encoding that has a signed byte as immediate operand.

So that's

```
83 C8 FF
```

`83` is the general opcode for `aluop rm32, imm8`, the ModRM byte `C8` has the components `11_001_000` where the `11` means the rm part is a register, the `001` is the /r field and turns the instruction into an `or`, `000` indicates the rm operand is `eax`. `FF` is the imm8.

Comment: I don't understand. _src_ may be _imm8_ (to `AL`) or _imm16/32_ to `(e)AX`. Assuming `OR eAX` is single byte opcode then it expects at least TWO bytes (`FF FF` to `AH` as second operand). How single byte to `AL` could make `eAX` to be `FFFFFFFF`?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti that's not how it works, the 16 and 32 (and 64) bit versions of the instruction also have imm8 (sign extended) forms (incidentally, the 64bit version does *not* have an imm64 form, only imm8 and imm32)

Comment: You're right, if I understood correctly OR EAX, FFFFFFFFh is compiled as OR EAX,FFh with _x_ bit set, FF is signed 8 bit and _CPU sign-extends this value to the appropriate size before adding it to the operand._. My + 1 Highlighting, tnx!

Comment: Also, the instruction set reference explicitly says for opcode `83`: `OR r/m32, imm8: r/m32 OR imm8 (sign-extended)`

Comment: @Jester `83 /1` to be complete

Comment: it's a quick/short way to set the register to all ones [Purpose of OR EAX,0xFFFFFFFF](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4609/purpose-of-or-eax-0xffffffff)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc yes, it usually has a useless dependency on the register though (Intel/AMD, please fix this) so watch that dependency chain, particularly in loops.